# WebBrowser não consigo jogar meu texto na caixa de texto

Tags: c#, navegador-de-internet

Tenho um sistema rodando em um cliente e agora ele me pediu uma funcionalidade que estou alguns dias quebrando a cabeça e não consigo fazer.

Ele precisa que a aplicação poste nos grupos do facebook dele em determinado horário algumas publicações da academia, eu consegui fazer isso porém usando a url da versão Mobile do facebook.

Utilizando a versão normaç não consigo achar o elemento na pagina para efetuar a publicação, como na versão mobile não consigo pegar a imagem que é gerado no mural não atendeu ao cliente.

Para publicação na url M.FACEBOOK.COM estou usando o seguinte código.

```
HtmlElementCollection elements = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement currentElement in elements)
{

    if ((currentElement.GetAttribute("type") == "submit") && (currentElement.Name == "view_post"))
    {
        string postagem = txtPublicacao1.Text;
        HtmlElement elea = browser.Document.GetElementById("u_0_0");
        if (elea != null) elea.SetAttribute("value", TextoPublicacao);
        {

            await Task.Delay(1000);
            currentElement.InvokeMember("click");
            txtStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => txtStatus.Text += "*HORA Postado: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("G") + " ID -> " + qtdpostGrupo.ToString() + " LINK ->  " + e.Url.ToString() + "\r\n"));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pergunta importante: Tentou usar a API do Facebook pra isso?

Comment: Jbueno, a API não deixa publicar em grupos que ele não é Admin.